# Make a div scroll in one line

Tags: css, html, scroll, alignment

I need to have the text in a One-Line scrolling div, fitting inside both divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/F6pNm/26/

The goal is for **all** to fit on **one line**!

EDIT: I guess I wasn't specific enough, I need the links and the text to fit on the same line. This way, the scrolling is vertically.

**EDIT: This is now the closest to what I need. Only the scrolling aspect is missing. http://jsfiddle.net/BKvzV/4/**

Comment: I don't believe your desired result can be met purely with CSS. Is any scripting acceptable?

Comment: When you say the scrolling in vertically, you mean that long text should be continuing past the bottom of the images, if necessary? And that the only scrolling is that typical for the entire page?

Comment: @Guth : I would prefer not, but if you can I would like to see what the code would look like. (I'd accept the answer until a pure css one shows up)

Comment: @Guth : No the scrolling area would have only 1 line height. This problem is inside my footer, which has no space under it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I read you correctly, you don't what your text to break, but to keep on going never leaving the line #1, so you can use CSS like this:

[Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/F6pNm/34/)

**YOUR CSS UPDATED**

```
#flash {
    float:left;
    width: auto;
    font-size: small;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

The difference is the [white-space:nowrap](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp);

**For does who can't see it:**

[image]

---

**EDITED to contemplate the edited question issue!**

[The new Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/F6pNm/41/)

---

**EDITED to contemplate the fact that all divs inside the footer must be side by side!**

The [updated Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/F6pNm/47/)

**Take note** that this solution uses Jquery to collect in real time the width of each div and sum all together to set the footer div. Without it, it can't be done!

---

**EDITED to have all 3 divs side by side within the wrapper width**

*in the Fiddle example, the wrapper is the body*

[The new Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/F6pNm/49/)

Comment: The text still appears on a different line and I need it to fit on the same line as the links

Comment: Just added a print screen to prove it works! The issue in your case may be some where else!

Comment: @Zuul, un-maximize your browser, make it smaller. That should prevent it from still looking correct, no?

Comment: The text needs to be on the same line as the links, not on a separate line.

Comment: Nop, just did it! It continues to be a beautiful line!

Comment: You didn't mentioned that on your question before!! I'll adjust it for you!

Comment: Your Fiddle still has two lines to show all the divs! You must understand that all the content must fit on one line!

Comment: See the new Fiddle added, it solves your problem :)

Comment: I guess you love to find exceptions I haven't specifed... This needs to fit dynamically with the current width of the page... Not make the page XXLarge

Comment: erm... you are a real piece of work! wait a second, I'll update the Fiddle!

Comment: And there you have it! take a look at the last Fiddle!

Comment: You're welcome Marleyzs, keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

**as far as I know There is no way *** to have 3 divs compete over the same space (100%), when they are all set to `width:auto;`. Even if you use `overflow`, or `in-line`, or the other methods suggested so far, I think the left div will always take the space it needs, then the middle, then the right... *unless* you use set widths

I don't know if that's possible since you are using `width:auto;`. that seems to allow the div to expand as wide as it wants, thus making it too large to fit in only the one line.

if you changed the links to set size, such as `width:10%`, then 4 of those links leaves you with 60%, so you can set `#flash {width:60%; overflow-x:auto;}` to have it scrollable and one line

Comment: The problem is the text and the links are loaded dynamically and I can't know the size that will be left for the text

Comment: No that would not work. The space for the links must stay dynamic since their content is constantly changing between pages

Comment: Well as far as I know, you can't have 3 auto width divs competing for the same 100% space if they are each set to width:100%

Answer (score 0):

```
#flash {
    float:left;
    width: auto;
    font-size: small;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    white-space:nowrap;  /* will put text in 1 line */
    overflow-x:scroll;   /* will add horizontal scroll bar should the length exceed the container */
}
```

Comment: The text needs to apear on same line as links, so the scroll would be vertical and not horizontal, I edited the question, didn't realize I wasnt specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
#flash {
    float:left;
    width: auto;
    font-size: small;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;

    /*These lines do the trick*/
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F6pNm/35/

Comment: but then wouldn't it not be in-line with the 'left' and 'right' floated divs?

Comment: Now you just edited it to say `width:auto` and then `width:100%` for the same #flash id....

Comment: Same problem, the text needs to apear on same line as links, so the scroll would be vertical and not horizontal

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, I have the middle div changing size based on the left and right div's.

jquery:

```
$(function () {
   var midWidth = $(document).width() - ($('#left').width() + $('#right').width());
   $('#flash').width(midWidth);
});
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BKvzV/2/)

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Added to the css of the div:

```
height: 36px;
overflow: scroll;
```

Its closer to what you probably want.
I am not sure how to get the box displaying one line only.

[Fiddle Update](http://jsfiddle.net/BKvzV/6/)

Comment: This is like a revelation, I only need to have the text centered between the other two divs (if only appears if you scroll out). And the text needs to be scrollable (with only one line viewable at a time)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BKvzV/4/ With this the resize works. All I need is the scroller now

Answer (score -1):

remove float:left

```
#flash { 
    font-size: small;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}​
```

Try This:

http://jsfiddle.net/damsarabi/F6pNm/40/

Comment: Nope, the line breaks after the text and before the last links.